# Slice a map given a list of keys in Kotlin

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, slice

Given a map, and a list of keys

```
val abc = mapOf(1 to "a", 2 to "b", 3 to "c")
val keys = listOf(1, 2)
```

How do I a get a map containing only the key-value pairs specified by `keys`? Something like

```
val ab = abc.slice(keys)
// equivalent to mapOf(1 to "a", 2 to "b)
```

I'm looking for something a bit more elegant than

```
val ab = listOf(1, 2).map { it to abc[it] }.toMap()
```

For example, in Elixir:

```elixir
abc = %{1 => "a", 2 => "b", 3 => "c"}
ab = Map.take(abc, [1, 2])
# equivalent to ab = %{1 => "a", 2 => "b"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`filterKeys`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-keys.html):

```
val ab = abc.filterKeys { it in keys }
```

And since it is Kotlin, you could even define your own [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) to achieve exactly what you imagined:

```
fun <T> Map<T, *>.slice(keys: Iterable<T>) = filterKeys { it in keys }

val ab = abc.slice(keys)
```

Comment: `it in keys` is not a good idea for large lists, this makes the entire operation to be O(mXn)

Comment: FilterKeys is super-slow, no idea, why.

Answer (score 3):

Solutions given in above answers does solve the problem but I think a small change is warranted.

Problem is that for every `key` in the `map` they check if the `list` `contains` that `key`, which is `O(n)` operation, this is ok for small lists but once you reach a certain size it becomes very slow. I suggest that you convert the `list` of keys to a `set` which reduces the contains operation to `O(1)` in average case. (Hence reducing carbon footprint :) ).

Following is the solution with above change incorporated.

```
val mapAbc = mapOf(1 to "a", 2 to "b", 3 to "c")
val keySet = listOf(1, 2).toSet()
val filteredMap = mapAbc.filterKeys { it in keySet }
```

Comment: It's no more efficient or fewer steps than `listOf(1, 2).map { it to abc[it] }.toMap()` from the question, though . It does feel slightly more idomatic, but in most cases I wouldn't bother with the set conversion, it's something to remember every time. Feels like this is missing from the standard library.

Comment: my bad, I overlooked that part. but the point is that contains operation on a list is expensive and if you need to perform multiple of them, then you need to reconsider your data structures. things always start small and before you know the list that should have stored only 100 elements end up storing 10000 items, making your runtime less than optimal

Comment: Actually, `.filterKeys(x in keys)` is brutally (!) slow for large lists, tested it myself.

Answer (score 1):

```
abc.filterKeys { it in listOf(1, 2) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
fun <K, V> Map<K, V>.slice(keys: Collection<K>): Map<K,V> {
    val resultMap = mutableMapOf<K, V>()
    for (key in keys) {
        get(key)?.let{resultMap[key] = it}
    }
    return resultMap
}
```

Test:

```kotlin
@Test
fun `should slice map by keys`() {
    // GIVEN

    val inputMap = (1..10_000).associate {
        UUID.randomUUID() to "value $it"
    }

    val nonExistingKey = UUID.randomUUID()
    val filterKeys = inputMap.keys.take(999).shuffled() + nonExistingKey

    // WHEN

    val startSlice = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val filteredMapSlice = inputMap.slice(filterKeys)
    println("Duration of slice: ${System.currentTimeMillis() - startSlice} ms")

    val startFilterKeys = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val filteredMapFilterKeys = inputMap.filterKeys { it in filterKeys }
    println("Duration of filterKeys: ${System.currentTimeMillis() - startFilterKeys} ms")
    assertThat(filteredMapFilterKeys).isEqualTo(filteredMapSlice)

    // THEN
    
assertThat(filteredMapSlice).hasSize(filterKeys.size - 1) // non-existing key should have been filtered
    assertThat(filteredMapSlice.keys).doesNotContain(nonExistingKey)
    assertThat(filteredMapSlice.keys).allMatch { it in inputMap.keys }
    filteredMapSlice.forEach{ (key, value) ->
        assertThat(value).isEqualTo(inputMap[key])
    }
}
```

This is magnitudes (!) faster than `.filterKeys()`

```
Duration of slice: 3 ms
Duration of filterKeys: 1479 ms
```

Comment: How does it compare to the suggestion in the question?