# How to filter a list by using the ids of another list?

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of `ids`. I want to filter my list and only keep the values in that list that match the id.

```
fun filterHelper(ids: List<Int>, list: List<People>) {
     list.filter { ids.contains(it.id) }
}
```

But this is very inefficient. It is essentially traversing the list O(n^2). Does Kotlin let me do better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65939282/slice-a-map-given-a-list-of-keys-in-kotlin) about slicing maps recently. The answer is that there is no good built-in function, but you can work around by using a `Set` instead of a `List` for your ids, which gets you O(1) lookup time for the comparisons, so O(n) in total.

```
data class People(val id: Int)

fun main() {
    val people = listOf(People(1), People(2), People(3), People(4))
    val ids = setOf(2, 4)

    val filtered = people.filter { it.id in ids }
    println(filtered)
}
```

Output:

```
[People(id=2), People(id=4)]
```

---

It's worth mentioning that if you already have a list, you can easily convert to a set with:

```
list.toSet()
```